# Creating cookbooks without a workstation server

Tags: chef-infra

I have a chef server and a chef client. Is it possible to create a cookbook without a workstation server? Directly on chef server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workstation means *workstation* (your PC) and not *server*.

You cannot edit cookbooks directly in the server, which (like most modifications that you make by editing in the Web UI) render the concept of Chef and *Infrastructure as Code* useless.

Please think about your workflow and let somebody explain you the ideas behind Chef.

EDIT: Actually, the parts of the *workstation* role which result in updates to the Chef server should be done by a CI server/pipeline. Manually uploading cookbooks, data bags etc. to the Chef server is explained kind of everywhere. But it should be more of treated as a software project/artifact.